# How to use calculation from select for another calculation

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to use a named calculation from one select into another,using Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2.

```sql
select f.price * t.price as result_price, result_price-30/30 as percentage from table f join table t on f.to_id = t.from_id where f.from_id = 12 and t.to_id=205;
```

It gives me an error "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'result_price' in 'field list'". How can I make it see result_price in select statement, or do I just simply make a duplification and write "(t.price*f.price - 30) / 30".
Which one is more efficient?

Comment: try `(f.price * t.price)  as result_price` and `((f.price * t.price)-30/30) as percentage`

Comment: You can't use column aliases in the `SELECT` part of the query as they will not be evaluated in time. Make the duplication.

Comment: You could also use a subquery, but has more overhead than repeating the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign variable to calculation and then reuse it in query.

```
SELECT @result_price:=f.price*f.price AS result_price, (@result_price - 30)/30 AS percentage FROM ...
```

Comment: Caveat:  In 8.0, doing assignments in a `SELECT` is deprecated.  That means it will be removed in the future.